# How can I fix GPROF output error and directory error?

Tags: c, testing, gcc, codeblocks

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b) {
    int result = a + b;
    return result;
}

int subtract(int a, int b) {
    int result = a - b; // Bug: Change to a + b to introduce a bug
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    int y = 3;
    int z;
    int sum = add(x, y);
    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);

    int difference = subtract(x, y);
    printf("Difference: %d\n", difference);

    return 0;
}
```

This is my C code named main.c

I try to work gprof on this code:

```
gcc -o go2 main.c -lm -pg
```

It works in this code on cmd.

```
go2
```

It works fine in this code.

```
gprof go2 -p
```

This code does not work and gives an **error :**

```
go2: No such file or directory
```